# Springboot-Kafka: Bootstrap-servers with MultiNode Hosts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to connect to kafka consumers which uses multinode hosts.
Following property works with one multinode host, but not able to read multiple multinode hosts.

**Works fine:**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = example.dev.com:9092
```

**Only reading from one host even-though mentioned two:**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = example.dev.com:9092,example2.dev.com:9092
```

Here:

```
example.dev.com:9092 = node:9092,node2:9092,node3:9092
example1.dev.com:9092 = node:9092,node2:9092,node3:9092
```

Is it possible to connect to multiple multinodes using one consumerFactory like below:

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory()
    {
  
        // Creating a Map of string-object pairs
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
  
        // Adding the Configuration
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                   "example.dev.com:9092,example1.dev.com:9092 ");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                   "group_id");
        config.put(
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
  
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }
```

Comment: What is the number of partitions in topics?

Comment: Did you try `config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, List.of("example.dev.com:9092" , "example1.dev.com:9092 "));`

Comment: Yes this does not work since behind scenes each proxy has more than one ip address.

Comment: Kafka cannot be proxied easily. Clients must talk directly to individual brokers. Sounds like you have a server misconfiguration causing issues with your client.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap server(s) are just used to, err, bootstrap the connections.

It only needs to connect to one of them to get information about the cluster.

That server then returns "advertised listeners" and the client will only actually connect to brokers that have partitions that the client wants to consume from (or send to).

So, if all the topics/partitions are located on just one server, that's the one you will connect to.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest hack would be check the servers and collect some info to make sure that topics/partition are created in multiple nodes. Once this is confirmed, you can just run your consumer and see if you are getting the topic/partition events.

List of bootstrap servers are mainly for resilience. It is not necessary to consume from each one of them every time.